# how change quality of croped image in android

Tags: android, camera, size, crop

I made an android app that can take a picture from the gallery or camera.

Everything is fine, but when I crop the image, its size goes to 160px*160px.

I'm confused as to why it has changed the size of my picture....

```
private void doCrop() {

    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no app for crop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
      //  intent.putExtra("crop", "false");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 800);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 800);


        intent.putExtra("scale", false);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));


            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);


            //  mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue( mImageCaptureUri);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("app for crop?");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    startActivityForResult(cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });




            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [many image cropping libraries available](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: thank you for your link,I check it, but my code is the same with your link :(

Comment: Then you did not read what I linked to. You are using `com.android.camera.action.CROP`. **Do not do this**. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of camera apps, with widely varying behavior for this `Intent` action, plus devices that do not support this `Intent` action at all. Do not use the `CROP` `Intent`, but instead [use a library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) or do your own image cropping inside your own app with your own code.

Comment: thank you a lot, I find a solution that help me work with **com.android.camera.action.CROP**. again thanks for your link and your attention